# Not able to find smart capture form while defining entry source in journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, smart-capture

Hi i am creating a new journey and trying to add a data source in it but its not showing me the smart capture form.

I have included that form in my cloud pages and checked it for using in journey.

I believe that the form i am looking is already being used earlier. but i have deleted that journey. So is their any way so that it shows me the smart capture form in data entry source.

[image: define Entry Source screen shot]

Comment: @Ashish--> Create new capture form then try

Comment: Ya i also got the same solution but there must be some other way otherwise i have to recreate the form always. Thanks @pkharries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the only way to use a SmartCapture form in a second journey is to copy the initial journey which the SmartCapture form is associated. If you have already deleted all versions of the previous journey, the only option at this time is to create a new SmartCapture form.

Comment: Hi Travis, Is this the only solution available right now?

Comment: Hello @PardeepSingh. To my knowledge it is currently still the only workaround if the original Journey has been deleted so that a copy cannot be made.